# Why does this ThreeJs plane appear to get a kink in it as the camera moves down the y-axis?

Tags: three.js

I have an instance of `THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry` that I apply an image texture to like this:

```
var camera, scene, renderer;
var geometry, material, mesh, light, floor;

scene = new THREE.Scene();

THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "someImage.png", undefined, handleLoaded, handleError );
function handleLoaded(texture) {

  var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(
    texture.image.naturalWidth,
    texture.image.naturalHeight,
    1,
    1
  );
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: texture,
    overdraw: true
  });
  floor = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  floor.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
  scene.add( floor );

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, texture.image.naturalHeight * A_BUNCH );
  camera.position.z = texture.image.naturalWidth * 0.5;
  camera.position.y = SOME_INT;
  camera.lookAt(floor.position);

  renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
  appendToDom();
  animate();
}

function handleError() {

  console.log(arguments);
}

function appendToDom() {

  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene,camera);
}
```

Here's the code pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qELxvj?editors=001

( Note: ThreeJs "pollutes" the global scope, to use a harsh term, and then decorates `THREE` using a decorator pattern--relying on scripts loading in the correct order *without* using a module loader system. So, for brevity's sake, I simply copy-pasted the source code of a few required decorators into the code pen to ensure they load in the right order. You'll have to scroll down several thousand lines to the bottom of the code pen to play with the code that instantiates the plane, paints it and moves the camera. )

In the code pen, I simply lay the plane flat against the x-y axis, looking straight up the z-axis, as it were. Then, I slowly pan the camera down along the y-axis, continuously pointing it at the plane.

As you can see in the code pen, as the camera moves along the y-axis in the negative direction, the texture on the plane appears to develop a kink in it around West Texas.

Why? How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: For info, google perspective-correct texturing and see http://extremelysatisfactorytotalitarianism.com/blog/?p=2120

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen similar behaviour, not in three.js, not in a browser with webGL but with directX and vvvv; still, i think you'll just have to set widthSegments/heightSegments of your PlaneBufferGeometry to a higher level (>4) and you're set!

Comment: Works like a charm! Makes sense, too: more segments, more detail, less errororors! Thank'y

Comment: Exactly! With only two triangles making up the plane it can only deal with distortions to a certain amount. Glad to hear it worked!